# Facebook Device Login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to have users login to facebook with a desktop app and am following this guide and am on the "Generate a Code" step: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices#tech-step1

I am trying this request using the [graph API explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I select `POST` and apparently `v8.0` is the only choice and then the request is `device/login`.

The parameters in JSON I'm using are:

```
{
    "access_token": "<app_id>|<client_token>",
    "scope": "user_status,user_posts",
    "type": "device_code"
}
```

I get this error message: "(#190) This method must be called with a client access token."

I grab my `app_id` from the top of my facebook app dashboard and I grab the `client_token` from the `Settings > Advanced` section.

I've also tried passing in the App Access Token I get when I do an `oauth/access_token` call using my `app_id` and `app_secret`, but that has the same issue.

When I try this request in my C# code I'm using a code like the following:

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login?access_token=1234|ABCDEFG&scope=user_status,user_posts";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I've tried every combination of `app_id`, `app_secret`, `client_token`, and `access_token` I can think of instead of the "1234|ABCDEFG" portion here but I just get "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

I'm sure it shouldn't be this hard to do a device login for facebook and I'm missing something.

Comment: You are not actually trying to post JSON though, right? These need to be normal POST parameters.

Comment: @CBroe Well I assume the graph explorer tool is converting those JSON params into a real URL like I try to do from code later on. Is there anything wrong with that second url format?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's too late to answer to your question.
actually I faced with same issue when I trying on postman.
simply I sent (access_token) as params instead of headers and I got respond.
hope to usefull.